# RVM Command: source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm going through the rails by example tutorial series. I'm trying my best to find solutions prior to asking questions, so if I have missed anything I apologise.

Every time I need to boot up RVM from the command line in terminal I need to punch a command so that RVM initialises: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Is this normal? It seems that I cant get the RVM commands to work unless I punch in this code prior. Note I only have to enter the command once, not every time I need to enter an RVM command.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Note if you are on **Ubuntu** the command may be `source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
# This loads RVM into a shell session.
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

So you don't have to manually type it for every session.

Comment: May I ask what this specifically does? The syntax seems a bit perplexing for someone not well-versed with Shell.

Comment: it does not work for me, im using ubuntu 14.04 and rvm 1.25.25 (stable). i tried to put this in `~/.bashrc` file, and also `source /home/pallavsharma/.rvm/scripts/rvm` i have to manually run this every  time to use rvm in terminal.

Comment: @Mirko What is the difference between putting this in `~/.profile` and putting it in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: For me, it worked when I pasted this into my `~/.bashrc`. It did not work when putting it in `~/.profile`. I am on the latest version of Linux Mint.

Comment: @PallavSharma it should work, maybe you missed reloading your bashrc. Its done by: `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I was just about to throw my screen off the window when I found your answer! Thank you sooo much!

Comment: @ConAntonakos `. xy` does more or less the same thing as `source xy`. [In contrast to `./xy`, it runs the executeable in the same shell, not a subshell](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/sourcing-vs-executing-shell-script). That is important as parameters are set and exported such as environment variables. [`[[ -s xy ]]` tests, if xy is an existing FILE and has a size greater than zero](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/test.htm). So basically the command checks if rvm exists and sources it if so. Mind the spaces with `[ xy ]`

Answer (score 2):

**Further Tip**

If you want to use gnome terminal (comes as standard in Ubuntu) with rvm, you can do the following:

- Edit the default profile. Check the following setting:

  ```
  "Run command as a login shell"
  ```
- This will stop loading the standard .bashrc by default. Fix this by making a soft link of .rvmrc pointing at .bashrc in your home directory

  ```
  cd
  ln -s .bashrc .rvmrc
  ```

Comment: This is not bound to the gnome terminal, but to basically all of them. Many deliver an option like this. To try if it is the reason, you can use `bash --login` as rvm will probably suggest. You can consider [this answer over at AU](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023687/830570) for a imho cleaner solution then `ln -s .bashrc .rvmrc`. Or you could change it to relative paths like that: `ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/.rvmrc`

Answer (score 1):

Try closing terminal and then re-opening it to install a specific version of Ruby as seen [in this video at 2:32](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THG3BKy6JEI&t=152).
For example, I typed `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Then I quit and reopened the terminal, typed `rvm install 2.2.3`  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your rvm command is not found:

0. (to check, enter the command  `rvm list`, which gives:)

```
/bin/bash: rvm: command not found
```

---

To solve it, follow these steps:

1. Install rvm
2. `whereis rvm`

```
rvm: /home/username/.rvm/bin/rvm
```

3. `source ~/.rvm/bin/rvm`

now test your rvm again

```
rvm list
```