# Ruby on Rails Bash Profile Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bash, sublimetext2

I'm trying to learn to use Ruby on Rails (going through Hartl's tutorial for 3.2) and I'm trying to get some command line tools to work from the command prompt in Terminal. In this particular example I'm trying to get Sublime Text 2 to work. Everything is setup, but when I run subl --help, for example it returns

-bash: subl: command not found

I followed all the directions in this link - http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

and I also used Stack Overflow to try to figure out how to solve this error and it seems to be a bash profile problem, but I don't know how to access, or modify this profile to get things working. Can you offer any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using OSX Lion, you may not have a `.bash_profile` file. Use the answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26928/no-bash-profile-in-os-x-lion) for help in creating/using one, and then put the exports suggested by the howto at sublimetext.com in it.

Comment: Thanks for this! Now, just have to figure out what's going on with the permissions being denied. Getting this back now...

ln: /bin/subl: Permission denied

Comment: Try: `chmod 777 /bin/subl` and `chmod -R 777 "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/"`. If those work, it was a perms problem. If you're concerned about permissions security, you could dial them back from 777 to something else like r-xr-xr-x.

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I'm into another error now. Referred to this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842566/rvm-command-source-rvm-scripts-rvm

as I was having trouble getting RVM to load in every new terminal window I opened and after following their instructions for the .bashrc I'm getting no command prompt at all....

Comment: To fix your current problem (corrupted shell profile), follow the directions here: http://superuser.com/questions/303516/open-hidden-configuration-files-without-using-terminal to revert the changes to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile folder`.

Comment: To fix the greater problem (starting RVM):
When you say you're following their instructions: are you putting it in .bashrc or .bash_profile? Try changing to the other. Also, copy & paste the command ([[ -s etc etc....) into a terminal and run it first before putting it in your .bashrc or whichever; that should expose the error/issue that causing your terminal to choke.

Comment: Also, this might be your RVM problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767135/rvm-and-bash-profile

Comment: All's well now! Thanks so much for the help. Going to get int a bit more today!