# why need to define source to RVM every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

When I want to run rails server it's not working because I need to define every time RVM source in terminal. Like that

`~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

If i restart computer then need to define again source then RVM working..

How can I define it permanently in ubuntu 12.10. Please help me

Answer (score 6):

Try to add command `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` into your .bash_profile

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842566/rvm-command-source-rvm-scripts-rvm?rq=1)

Comment: thanks but i want to know where is .bash_profile file?

Comment: .bash_profile is located on your home directory `~`. I wrote you the command `echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile` which do everything what you need to setup rvm into your .bash_profile. You only need copy & paste this command into terminal.

Comment: Don't remember restart your terminal or start another one and try to run `rvm list`

Comment: I want write _Don't forget..._.

Comment: ok I will check it after 8 hours :) If you are correct then i will mark it right and give you points

Comment: Not working I have run this command and check :( echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Did you see `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` when you run `cat ~/.bash_profile | grep source`? Are you use **bash** as your shell?